# Python ctypes variables with repeated addresses

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

So I'm developing a shared library in C, and I'm currently writing some Python wrappers using [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). It's mostly fine, but I'm having trouble with the addresses of native C types (e.g. `c_int`).

Consider the following SSCCE:

**Structure**

```
root
-example.py
-pkg
--__init__.py
--foo.py
```

**foo.py**

```
from pkg import *

class Foo():
  def fun(self, value):
    x = ct.c_int(value)
    print "Val "+str(value)+": " + str(ct.byref(x))
```

**example.py**

```
from pkg.foo import *

print "Outside an object"
x = ct.c_int(1)
print "Val 1: " + str(ct.byref(x))
y = ct.c_int(2) 
print "Val 2: " + str(ct.byref(y))
z = ct.c_int(5) 
print "Val 5: " + str(ct.byref(z))

print "Within object"
foo = Foo()
foo.fun(1)
foo.fun(2)
foo.fun(5)
```

From what I understand form ctypes, I expect `byref` to return 3 different addresses in both cases (i.e., within `Foo.fun` and in in `example.py`), since each object should be different.

However, when instantiating a native C type from within an object's method (in my case, `Foo.fun`), I always get *the same address*.

Sample output:

```
Outside an object
Val 1: <cparam 'P' (0x7f79379440a0)>
Val 2: <cparam 'P' (0x7f7937944130)>
Val 5: <cparam 'P' (0x7f79379441c0)>
Within object
Val 1: <cparam 'P' (0x7f7937944250)>
Val 2: <cparam 'P' (0x7f7937944250)>
Val 5: <cparam 'P' (0x7f7937944250)>
```

The first prints give 3 different addresses as expected (0x7f79379440a0, 0x7f7937944130 etc) while the prints from within Foo always return the same address (0x7f7937944250). What gives?

Comment: The C data address of a ctypes object is returned by `addressof`. `byref` doesn't return the address. It creates a light-weight `CArgObject` that references the object's C data. It's only useful when passed as a argument to a function pointer. This includes `cast`, and others, since ctypes implements them using an FFI function pointer.

Comment: As to your example, the default repr of a Python object shows its address, which for a ctypes object is not the address of its C data buffer. You're seeing an artefact of the small-object allocator reusing the base address for the allocated `CArgObject`.

Comment: @eryksun, in "It's only useful when passed as a argument to a function pointer.", what do you mean exactly? [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) suggests otherwise: "ctypes exports the byref() function which is used to pass parameters by reference.".

Comment: FYI, functions created with ctypes are function pointers, i.e. instances of `ctypes._CFuncPtr`.

Comment: Let's try restating this more plainly. Use `byref` to pass a reference to the data of a  ctypes object. But `byref` doesn't return the integer address that would be passed since its purpose is to make calling more efficient. Use `addressof` to inspect the address.

Comment: Note that I'm trying to clearly separate the data buffer of a ctypes object from the object itself, since you seem to have some confusion on the matter. Every ctypes object has a pointer to a block of memory that it references, and that it may own (i.e. is responsible for freeing). But the repr of the object shows the address of the Python object itself, not its C data buffer.